# Symfony3/Twig: How to get access to var folder in TWIG

Tags: twig, symfony

I have images in my var folder under Symfony 3 -->

MyProject

- app
- bin
- web
- var --> uploads --> images -->  myFile.jpg

I want to get access in my twig file to this jpeg file. 
I use a global under 
`twig config: uploads_root_dir: /var/www/html/var/uploads`

So my complete Url would be like this:

```
/var/www/html/var/uploads/images/myFile.jpg
```

But it is no Image shown. I can't use asset and I also don't want to. Is it possbile to get access to this file?

Comment: Your web server does probably not serve the whole tree of your filesystem. Instead the document is probably something like `/var/www/html`. In your template you will then have to reference the path starting from the document root. It should then be just `/var/uploads`.

Comment: Doesn't work, my path now is /var/uploads/images/myFile.jpg and the image is not shown

Comment: Is that path actually accessible through your web server at all? And what path would that be there?

Comment: Create a `var` alias in your vhost pointing to /var/www/html/var/

Comment: Why are you putting them under var? Symfony kind of wants you to put your "public" files under web. That's where your css, js, and images should go. Then in twig you can do something like: <img src="{{ asset('images/myFile.jpg') }}" /> and Symfony handles making sure the path is correct

Answer (score 0):

Symfony (2 & 3) only expose the web folder.

You have two choices

- move your uploads to the web directory but it makes it accessible to everyone
- create a custom url that serve image if the user is authorized

exemple: (very abstract, just to have the general idea)

```
getImageAction($imageName)
{
  if(! $this->isGranted('ROLE_USER')) {
     // throw unauthaurize exception
  }
  $imagePath = $this->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'../var/uploads/images/' . $imageName;
  // then return the image file or its path
  // [...]
}
```